# How do I replicate a derived PBKDF2 key equally with Qt implementation and Crypto-js one?

Tags: qt, cryptography, cryptojs

I have a system that is ongoing and running, on which the passwords were generated and stored with **Crypto-js PBKDF2** function, by the code (obviously the salt and pass content here are fake) as follows:

```cpp
Crypto.PBKDF2('water',
              'saltsaltsalt',
              {keySize:8, iterations:10000}).toString()
```

And for that example I get :

> 04b72ee92a8850bfdbe7cf801348a6701d11931702dcecad52f0b3351bedd01c

Looking at **Crypto** code I see its default algorithm is **Sha1**:

```
cfg: Base.extend({
                   keySize: 128/32,
                   hasher: SHA1,
                   iterations: 1
                 }),
```

My first doubt starts here as by my understanding of `keySize`, the result should be 8 bytes long only.

When I  use the Qt implementation of the same algorithm:

```
auto iterations = 10000;
auto keyLen = 8;
auto res = QPasswordDigestor::deriveKeyPbkdf2(QCryptographicHash::Algorithm::Sha1,
                                              QString("water").toUtf8(),
                                              QString("saltsaltsalt").toUtf8(),
                                              iterations,
                                              keyLen);  
auto result = res.toBase64();
```

I get:

> BLcu6SqIUL8

In this case, the result complies with `keylen` but it does not seem anything alike to what **Crypto-JS** does.

I feel I have some fault of knowledge at conceptual level about replicating the same derivation of keys, given that my expectations about the length of the derived key are not what I get in **Crypto-JS** implementation.

I would like to generate the same output in **Qt**, as in **Crypto-Js**.

Answer (score 0):

[Topaco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9014097/topaco) said:

> For `CryptoJS.PBKDF2()` the length has to be specified in words (= 4 bytes), i.e. for an 8 bytes key, 2 has to be set. `toString()` returns the data hex encoded by default, for a Base64 (or Base64url) encoding the Base64 (or Baser64url) encoder has to be used:
>
> ```
> CryptoJS.PBKDF2('water', 
>                 'saltsaltsalt', 
>                 { keySize:2, iterations:10000 }).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64)
> ```
>
> This gives:
>
> > BLcu6SqIUL8=